# How to parse an HAProxy URL using logging or other tools

Tags: haproxy

Recently I had to debug a 404 on HAProxy. After a couple of hours of digging I found out that the acls in place had a rule which captured my URL pattern before the acl I intended to use for that pattern.

All well and good but then it occurred to me that there must be a way to configure either HAProxy logging or use an external tool whereby I give it a URL and it demonstrates the logic of which HAProxy would parse it and which rule would catch it first and where will it send it to. Something like EXPLAIN in postgres where it walks you through how the SQL query is being processed and analysed.

I’ve checkout the logging documentation, it is quite rich indeed and quite possibly could provide what I’m after but I’m looking for a TL;DR option to be honest :)

Thanks I’m advance

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to test an entire configuration in the same way that EXPLAIN would do, but you can test each ACL one at a time to see if a value would match by using the HAProxy Runtime API command `get acl`.

More info and examples is here: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/api/runtime-api/get-acl/